# Calculations on extracted data from excel using python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

i want to calculate the average score and GPA of grades i extract from an excel file. currently, i'm able to grab the column from the excel file and i figured out how to create lists based on manual input. however, i would like to take the column of number grades from excel and use those as inputs (instead of manual input) in order to convert them into GPAs and calculate the cumulative GPA. i obviously want to skip the courses without a score available. how do i use the extracted data from excel in GPA calculation? i'm new to python and working with excel so anything helps. thank you

```
Course                      Scores
Art II                        93
Spanish II                   100
Algebra II Trig Honors        96
Christian Scriptures          99
Chemistry   
American History Honors       87
Phys Ed
Chemistry II                  92
```

python code

```
df3 = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx')
scores = df3[['Scores']]
print(scores)

letters = []
points = []
score = float(input("enter: "))
if(score < 101):
    letters.append('A')
    points.append(4.0)
elif(score < 90):
    letters.append('B')
    points.append(3.0)
elif(score < 80):
    letters.append('C')
    points.append(2.0)
elif(score < 70):
    letters.append('D')
    points.append(1.0)
elif(score < 60):
    letters.append('F')
    points.append(0.0)

print(letters)
print(points)
```

Comment: Reverse the order of your buckets, start at 60, then 70, etc. Currently all numbers are less than 101, so the will go into that bucket first.

Comment: What is expected output form sample data? 2 new columns?

Comment: How do you expect to manage the empty scores?

Comment: the expected output would be in this case: 3.83 @jezrael

Comment: i want to skip empty scores @CarloZanocco

Comment: thank you for catching that @TrentonMcKinney

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you need [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) with `mean`, because categorical is necessary convert to floats:

```
bins = [0,60,70,80,90,101]
df3['letters'] = pd.cut(df3['Scores'], bins=bins, labels=list('FDCBA'))
df3['points'] = pd.cut(df3['Scores'], bins=bins, labels=[0.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0])

mean = df3['points'].astype(float).mean()
print (mean)
3.8333333333333335

print (df3)
                    Course  Scores letters points
0                   Art II    93.0       A    4.0
1               Spanish II   100.0       A    4.0
2   Algebra II Trig Honors    96.0       A    4.0
3     Christian Scriptures    99.0       A    4.0
4                Chemistry     NaN     NaN    NaN
5  American History Honors    87.0       B    3.0
6                  Phys Ed     NaN     NaN    NaN
7             Chemistry II    92.0       A    4.0
```

Comment: this worked great but do you mind explaining the first three lines? i'll also need it to do the opposite (convert letter grades to scores and GPAs), so i think it would help

Comment: @J.Doe - For first question `cut` is used for `Bin values into discrete intervals.` For second, opposite operation it is more problematic, because e.g. `A` is from `91 to 100`, so what is expected output?

Comment: so i can't use the same logic here if i wanted to convert letter grades to numbers and GPAs? for example, A -> 90-100 / 4.0, B -> 89-80 / 3.0, C = 79-70 -> 2.0, etc.

Comment: @J.Doe - I think my main problem is `GPA`, unfortuantely never use it. Can you give me formula, some more info?

Comment: GPA is basically Grade Point Average/ average of all grade point assigned based on letter or score. in this case, an A is represented by 4.0, a B is represented by 3.0, C is represented by 2.0, D is represented by 1.0 and F is represented by 0.0. i want to keep the number scale basic so NO A-, B+, C+, etc. A = 100-90 (4.0), B = 89-80 (3.0), C = 79-70 (2.0), D = 69-60 (1.0) and F = 59 and below (0.0)

Comment: OK, so it is `mean` in my answer?

Comment: yes, mean is the average of each individual grade point

Comment: @J.Doe - OK, I think we dont understand each other, what is expected output from sample data for GPA?

Comment: the solution you gave is perfect. exactly what i needed. my question is can i use the logic from your solution if i had letters column instead of scores column and get the other desired columns (Scores and points). i ask because you said opposite operation is problematic.

Comment: @J.Doe - OK, I think I got you. I think here the best is use `map` by dictionary like `df3['points1'] = df3.letters.map({'A':4.0, 'B':3.0, 'C':2.0, 'D':1.0, 'F':0.0})`, and similar for `Scores` like `df3['Scores1'] = df3.letters.map({'A':'100-90', 'B':'89-80'})`, add next values.